# Why do I lose connectivity to my SQL Server when running through Apache?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, windows-authentication

I am trying to deploy my Django project on my company LAN. I am able to get the site working. However, I lose connectivity to my Microsoft SQL Server when I run the site through Apache. Everything works fine in the development environment. I suspect that I am losing Windows authentication when I work through the Apache server. This is what my DB settings are in my settings.py file:

```
'mosaiq': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'MOSAIQ',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'HHCMOSAIQ01T', 
    'PORT': '', 

    'OPTIONS': {'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
    },
```

Any idea how to connect to my SQL Server using Windows authentication or does my problem lie elsewhere?

This is the error I get:

> ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MEDSTAR\$'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: configure the logs and get some output from the server first, then you can pinpoint the problem, there are many aspects of the settings that change outside the development server.